# Need to find the sum of all even numbers in 2D array (then divide it on the amount of all even numbers to get the average value)

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I think there's some stupid mistake of mine when I initialized two-dimensional array in 'while' or something

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int sumOfEvenNumbers(int arr[], int Rows, int Columns) {
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
            while (arr[i][j] % 2 == 0)
                s += arr[i * Columns + j];
    }
    return s;
}
void main() {
    const int rowCount = 4, colCount = 5;
    int b[rowCount][colCount] = { { 2, 5, 6, 7, 0 }, { 8, 6, 4, 7, 1 }, { 3, 6, 1, 9, 5 }, { 5, 6, 7, 3, 2 } };
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
            cout << setw(6) << b[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sum = " << sumOfEvenNumbers(&b[0][0], rowCount, colCount);
}
```

[Debugging details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUbyf.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to tell us what went wrong first.

Comment: This won't compile, much less run. `while (arr[i][j] % 2 == 0)` where `arr` is simply `int[]` is obviously not going to work.

Comment: Your `sumOfEvenNumbers` needs to be rewritten to process one dimensional arrays.  There isn't a need to even pass the row and column count, just the total number of entries.

Comment: Also the ```while``` should be an ```if```, right?

Comment: template<typename T>
int sum_even(T a, T b){
    return std::accumulate(a, b, 0, [](int a, int b){
        return b%2 ? a : a+b;
    });
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```cpp
while (arr[i][j] % 2 == 0)
```

with

```cpp
if (arr[i * Columns + j] % 2 == 0)
```

As has been commented, you could also just use one loop:

```cpp
for (i = 0; i < Columns * Rows; ++i)
```